# Spring Boot - Returning JSON with array of objects

Tags: java, json, rest, spring-boot

Using this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44839954/919480) as a hint, I developed a Spring Boot controller for `/greetings` to return greeting in different languages in JSON.

While I am getting the output in the format (array of objects) I wanted, can you please let me know if there is a better way?

```java
package com.example.demo;

import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.GetMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestController;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.HashMap;

@RestController
public class GreetingController {
    @GetMapping("/greetings")
    public HashMap<String, Object> getGreeting() {
        ArrayList<Object> al = new ArrayList<Object>();
        HashMap<String, String> map1 = new HashMap<String, String>();
        map1.put("en", "Greetings!");
        al.add(map1);
        HashMap<String, String> map2 = new HashMap<>();
        map2.put("hi", "Namaste!");
        al.add(map2);
        //
        HashMap<String, Object> finalMap = new HashMap<>();
        finalMap.put("all", al);
        return finalMap;
    }
}
```

Received (valid) output:

```
{
    "all": [
        {
            "en": "Greetings!"
        },
        {
            "hi": "Namaste!"
        }
    ]
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you just need array of objects you shouldn't choose map rather use `List` type. For example, if you have Greeting objects and you want to return a list of all greetings your `GetMapping` would be something like below:

```
@GetMapping("/greetings")
    public ResponseEntity<List<Map<String,String>>> getGreeting() {
        ArrayList<Object> al = new ArrayList<Object>();
        HashMap<String, String> map1 = new HashMap<String, String>();
        map1.put("en", "Greetings!");
        al.add(map1);
        HashMap<String, String> map2 = new HashMap<>();
        map2.put("hi", "Namaste!");
        al.add(map2);
        return ResponseEntity.ok(al);
    }
```

Using `ResponseEntity` ensures that you are returning right status code and as it's wrapping up your response, it's more maintainable.

**Edit:** For key value pairs that you have created using map you can use POJO.

```
class Greeting{
   private String greetingLangCode;
   private String greetingText;
   // getters and setters

 @JsonValue
public String info(){
 return this.greetingLangCode + ":" + "greetingText";
}
}
```

With this endpoint changes to

```
    @GetMapping("/greetings")
    public ResponseEntity<List<Greeting>> getGreeting() {
        List<Greeting> al = new ArrayList<>();
        al.add(new Greeting("en", "Greetings!"));
        al.add(new Greeting("hi", "Namaste!"));
        return ResponseEntity.ok(al);
    }
```

But in case above don't work, you will require a custom serializer to serialize like map's `key:value` pair.

Probably [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5430524/serialization-of-key-value-pairs-in-jackson) post is helpful. This post have a complete example of how to write custom `serializer` and `deserializer`.

Comment: So, adding individual `HashMap<String, String>` is the only way to populate the `List`? BTW, you might want to edit the `<List<Student>>` part.

Comment: Thanks! No, other way is you can use POJO actually. Updating student part as  I was thinking to give that example

Comment: Can you add a POJO example, please?

Comment: Have added the example, and also the link to post that in case JsonValue annotation don't work is helpful in writing custom serializer and deserializer.

Answer (score 1):

While you can use nested `List` and `Map` objects, your code becomes unreadable quite soon. It is better to create actual objects. E.g.:

```
public class TranslatedGreeting {
  private String language;
  private String greeting;

  public TranslatedGreeting(String language, String greeting) {
    this.language = language;
    this.greeting = greeting;
  }

  // add getters
}
```

Then use that in the controller:

```
@RestController
public class GreetingController {

  @GetMapping("/greetings")
  public List<TranslatedGreeting> greetings() {
    List<TranslatedGreeting> result = new ArrayList<>();
    result.add(new TranslatedGreeting("en", "Greetings!"));
    result.add(new TranslatedGreeting("hi", "Namaste!");
    return result;
  }
}
```

The resulting JSON will be like:

```
[
  {"language":"en","greeting":"Greetings!"},
  {"language":"hi","greeting":"Namaste!"},
]
```

This JSON structure is also easier to parse for clients as the keys are fixed on `language` and `greeting`.

If you really want to keep the original structure, declare a custom serializer like this:

```
@JsonComponent
public class TranslatedGreetingSerializer extends JsonSerializer<TranslatedGreeting> {
    @Override
    public void serialize(TranslatedGreeting translatedGreeting, JsonGenerator jsonGenerator, SerializerProvider serializerProvider) throws IOException {
        jsonGenerator.writeStartObject();
        jsonGenerator.writeStringField(translatedGreeting.getLanguage(), translatedGreeting.getGreeting());
        jsonGenerator.writeEndObject();
    }
}
```

This will output:

```
[
  {
    "en": "Greetings!"
  },
  {
    "hi": "Namaste!"
  }
]
```

Comment: but it looses the compact json structure that OP is expecting. For same, I have just shared how that can be fixed when using POJO.